# Electric potential diagrams

Tags: electricity

Despite having a degree in electrical engineering, sometimes I still don't get the fundamentals of electricity. Can someone please explain the electric potential diagrams in the following link: http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/circuits/Lesson-1/Electric-Potential-Difference

1. If one were think about electric potential as analogous to gravitational potential, there should be a gradual decline from the high potential (+) to low potential (-). Why isn't that seem to be the case?

[image]

2. If in circuit A, the potential has already reached zero at point C, how can the charged particles continue their journey to the lowest potential (point D)?

I have few more questions but these are the most pressing ones and it would be lovely if someone could find time to address these. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, all wires are perfect conductors, and so require zero volts to push a current through them.  With superconductors, that's actually true, but with copper wires, it's not quite true.

But even a tiny voltage is enough to push a current through a copper wire.

So for circuit A, there should really be a very slight slope from A to B, and from C to D.  But the vast majority of the voltage drop will still be from B to C.

Comment: Thanks, that fits more with my intuition. Another related question, I suppose this too touches the fundamentals. Let's consider a modified version of circuit A where we apply the same voltage, i.e. 1.5V but this time have two resistors in series. According to kirchoff's law the total voltage drop across two resistors should be equal to 1.5V. How does this happen? More like how does the voltage drop to an intermediate level after passing through the first resistor before moving close to zero after passing the second resistor ? Thanks.

Comment: That's Circuit B.  Voltage is the "pressure" that forces electrons through a resistance - the "electromotive force" (EMF).  For two resistors in series, the current through both must be the same.  The voltage across each is given by V = IR.  If the two resistors are equal, then half the "pressure" will be across the first resistor, and half across the other.  But we often measure voltages relative to "ground", or to the -ve terminal.  So measuring from the start to ground, you'll see the full pressure, and measuring from a point between the resistors to ground, you'd see half the "pressure".

Answer (score 0):

> 1) If one were think about electric potential as analogous to gravitational potential, there should be a gradual decline from the high potential (+) to low potential (-). Why isn't that seem to be the case?

There is and you would see it if you were able to measure the voltage at various points along the bulb filament. The connecting wire has very low resistance in comparison so there will be little, if any, easily measurable drop along those.

> 2) If in circuit A, the potential has already reached zero at point C, how can the charged particles continue their journey to the lowest potential (point D)?

Think more of a bicycle chain rather than individual disconnected links. When you stand on the pedal force is transmitted immediately even though the links take time to travel from the rear cog to the chain wheel. The electric field travels at a speed close to that of the speed of light but electron migration is measured in mm/hour.